# Simulating CTRL+Space to switch keyboard input with CGEvent appears to show keyboard switching menu

Tags: swift, cocoa

There is a known bug where selecting CJVK input sources with TISSelectInputSource does not work.

A solution `kawa` has [come up with](https://github.com/utatti/kawa/blob/9ac0222788b67b8d89c38b998a050e2d0beb7894/kawa/InputSourceManager.swift#L57) involves emitting the `Select the previous input source` shortcut (default is CTRL-Space).

Here is the code I've used to simulate the shortcut:

```
    let spaceDown = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: nil, virtualKey: UInt16(kVK_Space), keyDown: true)
    let spaceUp = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: nil, virtualKey: UInt16(kVK_Space), keyDown: false)

    spaceDown?.flags = .maskControl
    spaceUp?.flags = .maskControl

    spaceDown?.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)
    spaceUp?.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)
```

However, when this is run, a popup of the keyboard input sources is shown (instead of simply switching the source):

[image]

This is the menu shown when you *hold down* CTRL-Space, not when you simply activate the command.

A funny behavior I've noticed is that moving the mouse or pressing any key causes the popup to disappear, which not the cause when you *hold down* CTRL-Space.

The question is, how can I get the actual result I want from emitting the CGEvents?

Comment: Try pressing the Control Key: Control down, Space down, Space up, Control up. The Space events have the `.maskControl` flag set, the Control events don't.

Comment: @Willeke that works, thanks! Slightly unrelated, but do you know how to convert a CGEventFlag to a list of modifiers? I'm looking for a more elegant solution than using flag.contains() with every modifier.

Comment: @Willeke list of modifier key codes*** (e.g. kVK_Control)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @Willeke, the solution is to post the CTRL CGEvent (even when you set the .flags property):

```
    let spaceDown = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: nil, virtualKey: UInt16(kVK_Space), keyDown: true)
    let spaceUp = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: nil, virtualKey: UInt16(kVK_Space), keyDown: false)

    let ctrlDown = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: nil, virtualKey: UInt16(kVK_Control), keyDown: true)
    let ctrlUp = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: nil, virtualKey: UInt16(kVK_Control), keyDown: false)

    spaceDown?.flags = .maskControl
    spaceUp?.flags = .maskControl

    ctrlDown?.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)
    spaceDown?.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)
    spaceUp?.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)
    ctrlUp?.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)

    CGEvent.init(source: nil)?.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)
```

An interesting behaviour I noticed is that if I changed the keyboard shortcut to include more modifiers (e.g. CMD, Option, Shift), it continues to work despite me emitting just the CTRL event.