# How to use Swift or Objective-C send a system keyboard event (UpArrow with maskControl) in macOS?

Tags: swift, objective-c, macos

I need send a keyboard event to open Mission Control in macOS. Now I use `CGEvent`, and my code like this:

Objective-C:

```objectivec
        CGEventRef pushUpArrowDown = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(NULL, kVK_UpArrow, true);
        CGEventRef pushUpArrowUp = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(NULL, kVK_UpArrow, false);

        CGEventSetFlags(pushUpArrowDown, kCGEventFlagMaskControl);
        CGEventSetFlags(pushUpArrowUp, kCGEventFlagMaskControl);
        
        CGEventPost(kCGSessionEventTap, pushUpArrowDown);
        CGEventPost(kCGSessionEventTap, pushUpArrowUp);
        
        CFRelease(pushUpArrowDown);
        CFRelease(pushUpArrowUp);
```

Swift:

```swift
    let cgEventSource = CGEventSource.init(stateID: CGEventSourceStateID.combinedSessionState)
    
    func controlUp(){
        var keyDown = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: cgEventSource, virtualKey: CGKeyCode(kVK_DownArrow), keyDown: true)
        keyDown?.flags = CGEventFlags.maskControl
        keyDown?.post(tap: CGEventTapLocation.cgSessionEventTap)

        var keyUp = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: cgEventSource, virtualKey: CGKeyCode(kVK_DownArrow), keyDown: false)
        keyUp?.flags = CGEventFlags.maskControl
        keyUp?.post(tap: CGEventTapLocation.cgSessionEventTap)
    }
```

It not work. How can I open Mission Control? Send a keyboard event, or use some other API?

Java can open Mission Control, with this:

```java
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_UP);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_UP);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
```

So, if I call function in `.jar` with Swift or Objective-C, I can open the Mission Control, but I don't want do like this.

Comment: Where is `robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);` in Objective-C and Swift? Post the Control key events: Control down, arrow down, arrow up, control up.

Comment: In Swift or Objective-C, add flags like `CGEventSetFlags(pushUpArrowDown, kCGEventFlagMaskControl);` or `keyDown?.flags = CGEventFlags.maskControl`.    And I tried post control and upArrow, but not work.

Comment: Setting a flag is not the same as posting an event. See [Simulating CTRL+Space to switch keyboard input with CGEvent appears to show keyboard switching menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60364088/simulating-ctrlspace-to-switch-keyboard-input-with-cgevent-appears-to-show-keyb)

Comment: @Willeke Thanks for you answer. It's not work for `Control+UpArrow`, if just `Control+Space`, it works with add flags only need, even do not need post VKControl. You can run this code, then you will know my say.

Comment: People might have changed the mission control keyboard shortcut. I wonder if there is a better API for opening it that doesn't rely on the keyboard shortcut being unaltered.

Comment: @Alexander Yep, agree. And this app is just written for myself. Therefore, if I change the keyboard shortcut to `Control+C` or other letter keys, it works. But I wanna fix the Control and any arrow keys not working error now, even if it is different from what I originally wanted to do. haha :-)